# Kill (not osStopService()) service

Tags: android, android-service

How i can kill service that is started from my application

Code for start service:

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
```

I need kill service proccess, don't stop with `stopService()` method.

Comment: What does "don't stop with stopService() method" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare that mean that i wanna kill service & threads that are started from him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using:

```
public void stopService(Context context) {
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(
            YourActivity.this.getPackageName(),
            YourService.class.getName());

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    if (YourService.intentVariable != null) {
        stopService(YourService.intentVariable);
    }

}
```

write a stopService method and in it use the package manager to stop the service you want to, and experiment with the package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Services don't have processes of their own.  The execute on the UI thread just like an Activity does.  There's no process to end, unless you started your own via Thread or AsyncTask.  In that case, you need to keep an instance around and force them to end yourself in your service's onDestroy function.